# Windows Phone 7 app not appearring on program list on emulator after closing app

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xna

When I first started using the Windows Phone 7 emulator with Visual Studio everything worked fine. I could click the Windows button on the phone, go back to the main menu and see my app on the program list.
Recently the app has stopped appearing in this list when I click the Windows button.
I was just wondering has anyone else experienced this and if so did they manage to fix it?
I can still load the app by debugging in Visual Studio but it can be inconvenient at times.

Comment: never heard of this before. Have you got a way to repo the issue? does it happen to all apps? Have you tried repairing the SDK install?

Comment: Had this problem once, but restarting the emulator solved it. You can try changing your app's guid too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a game by any chance? Remember that the emulator doesn't have the games hub, so if you want it to show up on the main app list, you have to go into the WMAppManifest.xml file and change Genre="Apps.Games" to Genre="Apps.Normal".

Comment: That fixed the problem. I think initially it was "Apps.Normal" but I changed it to "Apps.Games" because it was a game not knowing what changing that actually did. But changing it back solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: of course, don't forget to change it back before you publish it ;-)

Comment: It was only a college project so I won't be publishing it but thanks again for the help!